# Same C code gives different outputs on IDEONE and PC

Tags: c, mingw, long-long

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long i,j;
    for(i = 1,j = 100;i<5000;i+= 50,j+=23)
    printf("%lld %lld\n",i,j);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this code on IDEONE can be seen here : http://ideone.com/YCbc9V
I am using GCC 4.8.1 on Windows XP, but instead of getting `j + 23`, I am getting all `0`s on the second column of the output.

The code is same and so is the compiler, then hat is causing the change in output?

Comment: Perhaps on your PC you have Visual Studio instead of GCC? With VC++ it's `%I64d`, not `%lld`

Comment: OP is not using Visual Studio but GCC. However, this may be mingw GCC, in which case it uses MSVCRT.DLL with the buggy `printf` that does not understand `%lld`...

Comment: @xanatos No, I don't have VC++ on my PC. I only use Notepad++ and MinGW (GCC 4.8.1). And AFAIK, I64u works only for unsigned long long int. What would be the correct identifier for long long?

Comment: @reb94 As written by R, try the `%I64d` :-)

Comment: On Windows, it is safest to use `%I64` rather than `%ll`. Assuming it is MinGW, compile with `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1` on the command line or at the top of the file, before any includes, use `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1`. This will select the MinGW-provided functions like `__mingw_printf` that allow `%ll`. Also, compile with `-Wall`, and it will warn you about an extra format character when not using the MinGW functions. However, that shouldn't be your issue...

Comment: And why use long long at all here? You're only counting to 5000--that will fit into an int (even a short).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker : Maybe OP has not time to wait until `i<9223372036854775807` ;-)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I had initially set the for loop till 50000000000 but after getting the wrong output I changed it to 5000 but forgot to change the variable type.